# How to merge a list of numbers with a list of operators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numbers, operators

I'm writing a program where I need to have numbers in a certain order with operations between them in a certain order. To illustrate, my input is 2 lists (of numbers and of operators):

```
number_list = [a, b, c, d]
operations_list = [+, -, *]
```

From these input lists, I need to slide the operators in between the numbers, keeping the same order. Like this:

```
a + b - c * d
```

*Yes, I know I can't put operators in lists like that. I'm just trying to help you guys visualize what I'm trying to do...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should be able to use `int`'s magic methods.

Comment: More specifically, `int` has methods that can be used like so: `int.__add__(9,2) == 11`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I think you misunderstood. OP wants to perform those arbitrary operations. The point is not to interleave anything here.

Comment: @danielcorin, I don't quite see how that could help me in this scenario...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I was adding the other dupe meanwhile, combining both will help them in solving it. First one will help in coming up with `a + b - c * d` and second one in evaluating it. There are more duplicates for solving mathematical expression in a string.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I don't think this is a dupe of that either, at least, I'm not convinced you need to use something as complicated as pyparsing for this. That pertains to mathematical expressions in a string. This is about a list of arbitrary numbers, and a list of arbitrary operators, and how to get the final answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It is going to be slightly complicated if you want the correct mathematical answer, simply merging them won't handle operator precedence. Your deleted answer for example gives the wrong answer mathematically.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yeah... fair enough.